# Getting the query string from a browser link

Tags: flash, actionscript

How can I get the query string value from a browser sting into my flash movie?

For example, the link is `www.blah.com/index.html?name=John`. The html page loads a flash movie, and I would like the flash movie to be able to access the variable `name=John`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming ActionScript 3.

Checkout:[Get current url to Flash swf using an External Interface call (circle cube)](http://blog.circlecube.com/2008/01/tutorial/get-current-url-to-flash-swf-using-an-external-interface-call/).

Pretty much it seems to be: `ExternalInterface.call(“window.location.href.toString”);`

Then I guess you can get what you need by finding from the string.

Or you can use FlashVars and pass what you need to:http://blogs.adobe.com/pdehaan/2006/07/using_flashvars_with_actionscr.html

In the embed tag it's: `FlashVars="one=1&two=2"` and param: `<param name="FlashVars" value="one=1&two=2" />`

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to read the variables via javascript or some server side language like PHP and send them to the swf like that:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
}

"yourflashfile.swf?variable1=" + getURLParameter("parameter1") + "&variabl2=" + getURLParameter("parameter2")
```

Then in ActionScript use:

```
var variable1:String = loaderInfo.parameters.variable1 || "";
```